# Joblib ValueError when using multiprocessing on Python3.7 kernel in Vertex AI

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, vertex, joblib

I have been struggling for a few weeks with a recurring error. It appears in various contexts whenever I use multiprocessing with various packages. Here is an example of this error when I try using auto_arima() from mdarima package:

```
somenameProcess-3 failed with traceback:
--------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/somename/backend/popen_somename_posix.py", line197, in<module>
prep_data = pickle.load(from_parent)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
```

I get n copies of this error message for each vCPU I have.
auto_arima() function runs just fine with n_job=1, but fails with a message above when I provide n_jobs more than 1 (or -1).
I tried reinstalling joblib. Any joblib version after 1.0 gives the same error.

EDIT:
In addition to this, I get an error message:

```
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7fbaa9e62b10 state=finished raised TerminatedWorkerError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 360, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 797, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 864, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 782, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 531, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 178, in submit
    fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1115, in submit
    raise self._flags.broken
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

The exit codes of the workers are {EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1), EXIT(1)}
```

I am quite sure that I am not running out of RAM.